# fill fields of iframe from another domain with js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

What I'm trying to do is the following:

I have an iframe on my website from another domain but I don't like the way it is styled. Since it is not possible to alter the content of the iframe since it's from another domain I was wondering if the following approach would work.

I'm not going to show the iframe. The fields that are in the iframe are filled from fields on my page. This way I can style the form my own way.

Really hopes someone could tell me if this is possible or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The fields that are in the iframe are filled from fields on my page

That isn't possible. The same origin policy prevents accessing the DOM of the other page to write your own content to the fields.

Comment: Is there another way to achieve some sort of styling or only from the source domain?

Comment: No. The same origin policy prevents you from mucking about with content from other sites without their cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible and if it was it would be completely un-secure.